# Difference between Isolate vs Thread vs Process?

Tags: flutter, dart, concurrency, multiprocessing, dart-isolates

As we know flutter app runs in an isolates. Somewhere I read that isolates are not system processes. So what really an isolate is and how it's different from process.

Comment: they are like java `Thread`s

Comment: Java Threads shares memory right ?

Comment: yes, this is the difference - since in dart you cannot share anything - all you can use to talk to some isolate are `SendPort` / `ReceivePort`

Comment: Would be great if you could explain more.

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/an-introduction-to-dart-code-and-isolate-em3j34u1, just google for `dart isolates` - you will fine a lot of articles on that at medium.com

Comment: From the perspective of your code, isolates are similar to processes.  However, isolates run within the same system process (e.g. a Dart VM).  They therefore wouldn't give you the same security protections that the OS provides from separate processes.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. But there is no definite answer, because **it depends** on the language **implementation**.

Let me just quote the [docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/concurrency) (emphasis mine):

> Within an app, all Dart code runs in an isolate. Each Dart **isolate has
> a single thread** of execution and shares **no** mutable objects with other
> isolates. To communicate with each other, isolates use message
> passing. Although Dart’s isolate model is built with underlying
> primitives such as processes and threads that the operating system
> provides, the Dart VM’s use of these primitives is an **implementation
> detail** that this page doesn’t discuss.
>
> Many Dart apps use only **one** isolate (the main isolate), but you can
> create additional isolates, enabling **parallel** code execution on
> multiple processor cores.

As you might know, threads and processes are managed by OS.

Isolates are managed by Dart runtime, and they use underlying OS threads and processes.

> The Dart runtime controls the main isolate (where code normally runs)
> and any other isolates that the app creates.